# Is it feasible to make sure your flight would not be a codeshare in advance?

Tags: airports, airlines, code-share

I want to definitely avoid a codeshare flight. Usually, when you book a flight, the information about codeshare is shown on the booking site/page.

However, this might not be always the case; especially if your airline is [an operating carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeshare_agreement), the information about codeshare might not be displayed.

Also, I guess there exists a case that your scheduled flight is going to be codeshared only after you completed your booking. I might be wrong in this regard, though.

However, I definitely want to avoid the codeshare. Is it feasible to avoid it, or if not, is there still a way to discern or predict if a flight will be codeshared, from a set of variables such as cabin size, flight date, flight time, airport, airline, etc...?

Comment: Why do you care if it's a codeshare?

Comment: If your airline is the operating carrier, then your flight may carry the codes of other airlines as well. For example, UA999 is also LH 8855. It's operated by United on a United aircraft. If you're booked with the operating carrier, why do you care that the flight may have other flight numbers with other carriers?

Comment: @JonathanReez To tell you the truth, I don't like passangers from specific airlines. Let me keep the reason in secret but it is not a racist reason.

Comment: You know they sell airline tickets to anybody, right? Like the same people can go to another airline's websites and buy tickets over there.

Comment: In that case, you can't fly because every flight is a codeshare in some way.  Technically, all 'regional' flights are code shares even they are branded by the main carrier.  Only LCC's don't have codeshares, Ryanair, EasyJet, Spirit, Frontier, those kind.  Every Alliance (OneWorld, Star, SkyTeam) flight carries multiple codes.

Comment: @Blaszard A more fruitful approach would then be to find out whether a certain flight also has a code from that certain airline. Because “avoiding code share” is both absurdly broad and nearly impossible. But note that even that would not be a guarantee of anything, airlines can also sell tickets on other airlines without code share. Finally, if anything, the crowd on a certain flight will probably depend a lot on the route, time of day and price point. It's difficult to imagine that many people are so wed to an airline that they only show up when this airline starts offering a code share.

Comment: @Johns-305 That is absolutely not true.

Comment: @Johns-305 LCC have codeshares, I got on it.

Comment: Yes, I see EasyJet does codeshare now.  Good for them.

Comment: @Johns-305 And why do you conclude I can't fly? It is not as stressful to the extent I give up my travel. I'll endure it if it is codeshared; just want to know how to mitigate the chance if at all possible.

Comment: Because if you are trying to avoid flights that will never carry another airline's code, then your options will be very, very, very limited.  And if that's the case, you are right that it can change.  Norwegian, RyanAir and Spirit could announce an agreement tomorrow.

Comment: Codeshare flights aren't the real problem, so even if you could do it, it would not be a solution.

Comment: _"To tell you the truth, I don't like passangers from specific airlines. Let me keep the reason in secret but it is not a racist reason."_ It's hard to imagine what other direction this could take, particularly since you're refusing to tell us what the reason is.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that many flights are sold as part of an interline itinerary that are not codeshares.  So even if a flight is not marked by another airline, they can still sell tickets and connect passengers.  Under the hood, that's all a codeshare is.  And airlines have many more interline options then codeshares.

Comment: `To tell you the truth, I don't like passangers from specific airlines. Let me keep the reason in secret but it is not a racist reason.` Woah! Nobody asked if it was a racist reason! Seems we now know why you're trying to avoid some carrier...

Comment: Your comments haven't been helpful at all, I am voting to close the question. It seems you have some problem you don't want to tell us about and that makes both the question and its answers close to useless. A codeshare is not something you "endure", you might not even notice, so what's the real issue?

Comment: Well then I disclose it; it is two of Japan's airlines that I desperately want to avoid, since Japanese children are insanely noisy, run around everywhere and keep issuing an insufferably discomfortable shrieking voices and Japanese parents never care about their children. It is highly unpleasant but you almost always have nothing to do there and just must endure it for hours. I rarely have any problems on children from other countries (sometimes China and Taiwan's are noisy, though) and I rarely have any problems on other Japanese passangers, either. Just those parents with children sucks.

Comment: And why is this going to be seen as an unclear question? The question is, as @chx said, *crystal clear from day one, incredibly odd but crystal clear*, I believe. No matter what the reason is, the gist is *how to avoid the codeshare flight*, which is clear enough to fit the question.

Comment: It's remarkable how overly-complicated this QA has become.  To check if a flight is a codeshare, use Expedia and - you guessed it - CLICK ON FLIGHT DETAILS. It instantly tells you what the flight actually is, like "AA 123", and then "Operating as BA 456".

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes I know, but sometimes it might not display it if you're booking a ticket that works as an operating carrier.

Comment: hi Blas - well, I have not seen that, Expedia has always given the actual metal information.  But sure, if so, I don't know.  Phone the airline?

Comment: Possibly legitimate reason to avoid a codeshare: passenger experiences that airline X has worse performance, reliability, service, etc., chooses to book through airline Y, and wants to ensure that the flight is actually operated by airline Y and not by airline X.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to ensure that Airline Y operates your flight if you like the service offered by Airline Y and don't want to get stuck with the inferior service of Airline X. But that's not what this question is about. This question is asking about how to ensure that Airline X doesn't also have a flight number associated with your flight, even though you know Airline Y operates your flight and you're happy with that, because you don't like some of the people who fly Airline X and you think they somehow never ever fly Airline Y unless there's a codeshare, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way to see all the flight numbers that a flight is sold under is to consult the departure flights information page of the departing airport's website (of course, some airports may not maintain such a page, but all those of a reasonable size very probably do). For example, here is a screenshot of that page for [LGW (London Gatwick)](http://www.gatwickairport.com/flights/?type=departures) airport:

[image]

It can be clearly seen that flight BA2630 to Alicante is not operating under any other flight number, and so is not a codeshare, whereas flight BA2606 to Naples has two other flight numbers (the probability of AA operating a flight from London to Naples, let alone at the same time as BA, is basically zero).

Note, however, that this does not necessarily solve your underlying problem, because it is possible for an airline to sell tickets on a flight of another airline **under a flight number of the operating airline**. And in this case, this is not a codeshare, and there is no way to detect it.

Comment: Thanks and I don't mind it if an airline sells it using the name of the operating airline, which is not the problem at all.

Comment: The FIDS will only show the codeshare when there are passengers booked under that code since that's what is on their Boarding Pass. So there are likely AA and VY passengers booked on BA2606.

Comment: You can tell by the flight number that AA 6236 is a codeshare, as is VY9987.

Comment: @Johns-305 *"The FIDS will only show the codeshare when there are passengers booked under that code"* I highly doubt this, but would be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: You can always check tomorrow.  But think about it, if every flight showed every possible codeshare, each flight would have 5-10 or more entries.  The strangest part about that is AA6236 is really BA190 which is not a Naples bound flight.

Comment: Your comment seems to contradict what you said earlier.  You said you don't like passengers of a specific airline, then above you said you don't care if they sell it using the name of the operating airline.  It will be the same passengers buying the flights from airline XYZ, whether it is a XYZ code-share number or the operating airline's number.

Comment: @fkraiem Here is the proof: BA2630 (on the photo) has an IB7594 codeshare and that's not on the photo. This was trivial to find: just go to the Iberia website and search for London-Alicante.

Comment: @chx All right, but I suspect this may be an overlook on the LGW website, and not a reflection of the current state of bookings. The [arrivals information page of Alicante Airport's website](http://www.alicante-airport.net/arrivals.php) does list the IB number, as does the FlightStats page it links to.

Answer (score 7):

> I definitely want to avoid the codeshare. Is it feasible to avoid it

No.

> or if not, is there still a way to discern or predict if a flight will be codeshared, from a set of variables such as airline

As far as I am aware, practically any flight in an alliance can be booked with any airline in the alliance. You need to look outside of alliance and at airlines not flying transoceanic routes because those are too expensive not to code share -- except perhaps Norwegian. Low cost airlines typically do not code share, for example the EasyJet-Transaero codeshare on LGW-DME is the only codeshare EasyJet has. Ryanair and Wizzair has none. Countless small European low costs have none. Southwest has none either, there were plans with Westjet but there is nothing. Allegiant has none either and they advertise this.

Comment: I thought when I booked by YVR–YEG flight three years ago (operated by WestJet) that it had a codeshare BA code, but I could be remembering wrongly.

Comment: Just because you book with airline X a flight operated by airline Y does not mean it's a codeshare. It's a codeshare if the flight is sold to you under a flight number of airline X.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, its quite easy to identify and avoid codeshare flights.**  Though you may have to make separate bookings depending on where/how you buy the tickets.

That a flight is a codeshare is not at all hidden and has always been displayed as such during the booking process.

If you airline is the operating carrier, then it can't be a code share so that's not a scenario should worry about.

No, flights are planned well ahead and don't change the operating carrier.  If your operating carrier cancelled their flight, you could be rebooked on a codeshare but it would be quite obvious, not the least by the change in flight number.

No that most carriers use specific ranges of flight numbers for code shares, for example all AA codeshares are in 6000 range (IIRC).  So it's pretty easy to tell.

Comment: But you can’t tell in all cases whether RJ124 is a codeshare with any other airline if you book *via* Royal Jordanian — or any other example that you can think of.

Comment: > Yes, its quite easy to identify and avoid codeshare flights. -- if OP wants to avoid codeshared flights -- and I believe that's the case since they mention operating carrier -- for whatever demented reason then this is not true. In fact, it's very hard to determine whether the flight you booked will also be sold by another airline. How do you know whether TS677 is available under some airline as well?

Comment: I just did a search on rj.com form AMM-CLE and the ORD-CLE flight is clearly identified as RJ7492 - Operated by American Airlines.

Comment: But that's not the question!! The question is that if you fly RJ124 how do you know whether you can fly it as AA as well... at least that's what I think the OP asks.

Comment: @chx I think you misunderstood the question.  The OP wants the booking carrier to be the operating carries as well.

Comment: That is not a question, that is always crystal clear on search and book. Even Air Transat displays the flight is operated by Thomas Cook although you can't book it via Thomas Cook...

Comment: Check http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80416/is-it-feasible-to-make-sure-your-flight-would-not-be-a-codeshare-in-advance/80417#comment183413_80416 this comment by OP, I am right. You answered a pretty trivial question which this one is not.

Comment: @chx *"How do you know whether TS677 is available under some airline as well?"* One possibility is to check the list of departing flights on the departure airport's website, which will of course list all flight numbers for each flight.

Comment: I wrote the answer after that note but, he hasn't changed the question yet so my answer is still correct.  Modify the question and I may modify the answer.

Comment: The question was crystal clear from day one, incredibly odd but crystal clear. And I answered it. You presumed it's the common question and answered it. Well, it wasn't.

Comment: For example on [the list of departing flights from LGW](http://www.gatwickairport.com/flights/?type=departures), you see that BA2630 to Alicante has no other flight number, and so is not a codeshare, whereas BA2606 to Naples is also AA6236. Maybe this should be an answer...

Comment: No, it is not.  A 'codeshare flight' is one sold by one carrier and operated by another.  That is the only definition of a codeshare.

Comment: The FIDS will often only show the codeshare when there are passengers booked under that code since that's what is on their Boarding Pass.  So there are likely QF and WS passenger on that flight.

Comment: @Johns-305 I never said I want my flight to be the operating carrier. I just mentioned the operating carrier as that it might not show the codeshare note.

Comment: Sorry, but if it's not the operating carrier, then has to be a codeshare.  There's nothing else...???

Comment: @Johns-305. If I buy a ticket on flight NZ-0006 through air NZ (the operator), How do I know that won't also be sold as AA-xxxx? That's the question. Of course, there's no reasonable way to know that, that I am aware of.

Comment: I'm answering based on the specific meaning of codeshare.  Is BA190 a code share flight?  No, because BA is the operator.  Is AA6236 a codeshare? Yes, be cause BA is the operator.  There is no term for a flight that could have a codeshare.  The question would have to be "Is there a way to find out if a flight is or is not sold as a codeshare by an airline other then the operator?"  Sorry, but that's what the words mean.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to search the website of the airline you plan on flying with (or the one you prefer) and see if your destination is flown with by a partner airline or codeshare agreement.

Here is [an example for Emirates](http://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/193949/with-which-airlines-does-emirates-operate-codeshare-flights) which lists all the destinations that are flown by code-share partners.

This will get difficult if your airline is a code-share partner with a large network like Star Alliance, where you can end up booking a flight on American Airlines that is actually flown on Gulf Air. For these airlines, I find that their flight maps highlight those routes that are from partner or network airlines.

Comment: Take it one step further, search for flights between the cities in question on the day you are traveling offered by the unwanted airline.  Look if any are marked as a code share.  Also write down the flight times, so when searching on the preferred airline, you can avoid any with matching flight times to be doubly safe.